# Calling .whereKey method on a PFQuery

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete the data source in Parse after a user deletes a table cell. It's working just fine as I've tested different .whereKey methods but I can't seem to figure out which one to use in order to find the object that was actually deleted. What I currently have listed below returns the error: "No results matched the query."

Thanks

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        titles.removeValueForKey(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        var myItem = PFQuery(className: "Items")

        myItem.whereKey("price", containsString: "\(prices)")
        myItem.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                object?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                })
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you store tableview data? I mean the problem could be you're deleting cloud data but not local cells. Could you write ```cellForRowAtIndexPath``` method also?

Comment: The local cells are deleted. And when I call a different .whereKey method (say with a known string) it'll delete it in Parse. I just don't know which .whereKey method to use to capture which cell the user deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My humble suggestion is fetching objects from objectId for the convenience because sometimes you can get multiple objects from `whereKey containString` method and it can be hard to organize them.

You could store item's objectId's in array and than when you want to delete object use `objectWithoutDataWithClassName` this [method](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:) than call delete which is `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock` [method](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:) in block do what you want.

Hope it helps.